# Multiple Joins in MS Access 2010 not working

Tags: vba, join

I am trying to perform a multiple inner join between 4 tables I believe.  I have a table called TrainingT that holds all trainings for employees.  In this table, the TrainingTitle field is a lookup value from a table called LKP_TrainingTitlesT.  I have a combo box and what I would like to do is display 4 distinct fields, from the TrainingT table.  I would like TrainingT.ID, TrainingT.TrainingTitles, TrainingT.Vendor (This is from a lookup table as well that holds vendor names), and TrainingT.[TrainingLocation City] (city is also a look up value).

When I put the RowSource value (SQL statement) into the VBA code for Access I say:

```
Combo282.RowSource = "SELECT Data_TrainingT.TrainingID, LKP_TrainingTitlesT.TrainingTitles, LKP_TrainingLocationCityT.City, LKP_TrainingVendorT.Vendors" & _
" FROM ((Data_TrainingT INNER JOIN LKP_TrainingVendorT ON Data_TrainingT.Vendor = LKP_TrainingVendorT.ID)" & _
" INNER JOIN LKP_TrainingTitlesT ON Data_TrainingT.TrainingTitle = LKP_TrainingTitlesT.ID)" & _
" INNER JOIN LKP_TrainingLocationCityT ON Data_TrainingT.[TrainingLocation City] = LKP_TrainingLocationCityT.ID;"
```

Now, I have researched this INNER JOIN stuff a lot and I know that MS Access likes to have paranthesis around the different join statements but I have tried every possible paranthesis placements and followed other stack overflow examples and I still can not get it to work?

EDIT:  Added CInt() to "....ON CInt(Data_TrainingT.TrainingTitle) = LKP....) and it worked.  No more type mismatch.

Comment: It would be really nice if you could provide us with an error message or actual problem. Additionally it would be preferrable if you could include what database you are running against and how you connect to it.

Comment: It's encourage to answer (even [self-answering](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)) this question instead of "add the answer to the question".

Answer (score 0):

OP's EDIT:

Added `CInt()` to `"....ON CInt(Data_TrainingT.TrainingTitle) = LKP....)` and it worked.

No more type mismatch.